# How do i edit a usercontrol triggers? XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xaml, user-controls

So I am trying to add some "effects" to my custom made control.
I want to change a few properties on "IsPressed" but for some reason when I try to do this, I keep getting the error

> "IsPressed" is not recognized or is not accessible."

I am not sure if this is because it's a custom control or if its because I am missing something, I've never tried doing this with a custom control I've only done it with normal controls.
What is the proper way of doing this?

So what what I have is this

This doesnt do anything at all and I am not sure why

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="UserControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

And this would be the control

```
<UserControl x:Class="MasterViewDetail_MVVM.Controls.MasterView.MasterViewUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:designModel="clr-namespace:MasterViewDetail_MVVM.ViewModel.Nodes.DesignModel"

             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="60" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid Background="#2B2F42">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- Column 0 -->
            <!-- New SelectedItem Bar -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <!-- Color Circle (Blue Password, Green Note, Orange File) -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <!-- Main content -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Selected Item Bar -->
        <Border Background="#FFB400" Width="5"/>

        <!-- Color Circle -->
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Padding="8">
            <!-- Data Type background -->
            <Border Name="BackgroundRGB" Background="CornflowerBlue"
                    Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                    CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

                <!-- Data Type Text -->
                <TextBlock Name="DataTypeText" Text="P"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="White"
                           FontSize="20" 
                           FontFamily="Levenim MT"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <!-- DONT FORGET TO NAME THE TEXTBLOCKS! -->
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Padding="0 0 8 0">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <!-- Title OR Username -->
                <TextBlock Name="TitleText" Text="Happy@Some.com" FontWeight="Bold"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                           Foreground="#00AFE1"/>

                <!-- Content -->
                <TextBlock Name="ContentText" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ex tellus, rutrum quis eros in, bibendum posuere ligula. 
                           Cras at dictum leo, in pellentesque nisi. Sed sollicitudin sagittis lacinia. Quisque sed nibh egestas, vehicula neque in, accumsan lectus. Ut quis eleifend nulla. 
                           Aliquam orci nibh, elementum sit amet faucibus vitae, feugiat ac lacus. Suspendisse in posuere libero. Aenean eu condimentum sem. "
                           FontWeight="Light"
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                           Foreground="Gray"
                />


            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

EDIT

Comment: very simple: userControl class doesn't have IsPressed property. so you can't use it

Answer (score 0):

Just by judging from your example, I can see the issue. You made it so `IsMouseOver` changes the `Background` property of the `UserControl` to red. You then created a `ControlTemplate` for the `UserControl`, basically overriding the way the `UserControl` is built and you 'broke' the default connection of the properties to the `UserControl` itself.

This can be fixed by using `TemplateBinding`, but you missed the `TemplateBinding` for the `Background` property. Add it, and your example should work.